# Auto updating Views in PouchDB during insertion

Tags: pouchdb

Is there a way to auto-update Views, during insertion.

I insert something like ~2000 documents, in a go. After that my first query (during which it builds the view) takes more than 2 minutes (on MacBook Pro).

So i am wondering, i could reduce that time, if we keep updating the view, when we are inserting the documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, no. You can just manually call `db.query()` with `{limit: 0, stale: 'update_after'}` to force a refresh, though.